# jQuery get works but Axios doesnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, axios

I am sending a simple get request to my PHP BE, these are my requests in jQuery and Axios respectively:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/?do=vueTestComponent-ReloadTime",
  success: (data) => console.log(data)
});

Vue.axios.get("/?do=vueTestComponent-ReloadTime").then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Where jQuery returns correctly and finishes with code `200` and Axios returns incorectly and finishes with code `302`.

This is how I am loading `jQuery`:

```
<script src="{$basePath}/components/tinymce/tinymce.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is how I load `axios` in my `main.js` file of a Vue project:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
```

Also jQuery resolves much faster.

I cant figure out what am I doing wrong, they should both be identical. Is it a nuance of jQuery/Axios?

Comment: what's `JSON.stringify(data)` mean? see doc: `axios.get(url, config)`

Comment: Sorry @joaner, that was me trying to adjust the header, but it should not be necessary, since I am also not adjusting it for jQuery

Comment: Can you post where you load Axios and Jquery?

Comment: @RiadZT I am running them right after each other, but no matter the order, I get same results

Answer (score 0):

axios default **not** send cookie when cross-site, maybe this is the cause of the response 302.

see `withCredentials` option: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

```
Vue.axios.get("/?do=vueTestComponent-ReloadTime", {
  withCredentials: true,
}).then(...)
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly still the same result :/

Comment: @Jousi You can compare different points at two requests, sorry can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out, that I need to specify in the `axios defaults`, that my request is a `XMLHttpRequest`.

So I created a global variable for the instance of requests which are in fact `XMLHttpRequest` and the set up now looks like this:

```
window.axios_instance = Vue.axios.create({
  baseURL: '/'
});

window.axios_instance.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
```

Hope this helps someone!